# Second monitor via usb C using ASMEDIA ASM 3142

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, pci-express, usb-c

I would like to add a second monitor to computer unit, the setup is not very powerful (it doesnt have to be) it does not even have a graphics card in it. Nonetheless a second monitor will go a long way to the who will use it, although a typical USB A to HDMI adaptor will suffice, i was thinking of adding a USB 3.1 Type C PCIe exapansion board on it that is using the ASMEDIA ASM 3142 [just like this one](https://www.amazon.ae/Rivo-Express-SuperSpeed-Connector-Asmedia/dp/B07Z8962B8). One port can be used for the monitor and the other for other type C use cases like phones and external drives.

So first question will i be able to get a video output from this card? I mean i think it should be able to do it, i dont see why windows 10 cant handle this

Second when i searched for usb c to hdmi cables almost all of the listing [such like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075V5JK36) have a compatibility list , given that my use case is very niche will buying this type of cable work? Or should i just opt to buying a usbc to hdmi adaptor and use a generic hdmi to hdmi cable instead.

Comment: No, these XHCI controller cards won't get you any extra video output (unless you additionally use one of those DisplayLink-or-similar external video cards; I'm not sure if they have 2D/3D acceleration by any means). It has nothing to do with the OS, but the fact that USB-C alt modes relies on wiring in the motherboard.

Comment: While HDMI alt mode is a thing, it came much later after DP alt mode. Also, TB 3/4 do not support HDMI natively like they do for DP. Therefore, many (if not all) USB-C to HDMI cables on the market are active DP to HDMI cable. That's probably why they have a "compatibility list", since they have a chip for signal conversion, which more or less increased the chance of "being incompatible" (i.e. bug / design flaw).

Comment: @TomYan Well that is unfortunate, any recommendations on how can i add a second monitor without buying a graphics cad?